# jetty servlet mapping uri to files

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

With `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI` we can get the path the user entered when she accesses the servlet.

How do I write a servlet that maps these URIs to files in my home directory. for example, if the user enters the URL of the servlet

> "http://localhost:8080/webbtechnologies/html/index.html"

send the file

> C: \ Users \ User \ My Documents \ Web Technologies \ html \
>   index.html

to the user.

This is my code so far:

```
public class SimpleFileManagerServlet extends HttpServlet {
private String location;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {
resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
location = req.getRequestURI(); 
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.addServlet(SimpleFileManagerServlet.class, "/");

Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at jetty's DefaultServlet which exactly does what you want. In case you want to do additional things, you can just use the code from the DefaultServlet and extend it.

However giving your description of your use case DefaultServlet should be sufficient for you.

Here's the javadoc: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html

Have a look at the test webapp provided with the distribution on how to configure it in web.xml, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty's `DefaultServlet` will do this for you. All you really need to do is tell it where on your server to serve files from.

Try this:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    context.setResourceBase("file:///C:/Users/User/My Documents/Web Technologies");
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class), "/*");

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```